# C# BHO return value from Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer, bho, mshtml

I have a C# BHO which calls some JS functions in a document. Normally I did it like this (and everything worked fine):

```
IHTMLWindow2 wnd;
//...
wnd.execScript("testMethod(\"testData\");");
```

But now I need to return value from JS method to my BHO. I implemented test JS method which returns a string but when I use execScript nothing is returned. I started to read documentation [about execScript method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and found that now they recommend to use [eval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/12k71sw7%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) instead.

But I can't find any information on how to call this from my C# BHO. I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342200/how-do-i-call-eval-in-ie-from-c) and there is even c# example but it assumes that I host WebBrowser control and suggests to use Document.InvokeScript. And in MSHTML none of IHTMLDocument* interfaces have InvokeScript method. Am I missing something?

**EDIT 1:** Here is [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000371/return-value-from-execscriptihtmlwindow2) which kind of answers how to get return value from execScript. But its probably not smart to use execScript if MSDN says it is no longer supported.

**EDIT 2:** 
More code for this issue. First of all I have a JS function like this (in a file called func.js):

```
getElemHtml = function () {
    var myElem = document.getElementsByClassName("lineDiv")[0];
    // A lot more code goes here...
    alert(myElem.innerHTML);
    return myElem.innerHTML;
}
```

Then in my BHO I inject this script into the page like this:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("func.js"));
string scriptContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
IHTMLElement head = (IHTMLElement)((IHTMLElementCollection)ihtmlDoc2.all.tags("head")).item(null, 0);
IHTMLScriptElement scriptObject = (IHTMLScriptElement)htmlDoc2.createElement("script");
scriptObject.type = @"text/javascript";
scriptObject.text = scriptContent;
((HTMLHeadElement)head).appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode)scriptObject);
```

Then in another part of BHO I want to get return value from getElemHtml():

```
var retVal = ihtmlWindow2.execScript("getElemHtml();");
```

but retVal is null. I see that script is executed and I see that return value is not null because I see alert window with return value. What I want is a return value from this JS function in my C# BHO code. It looks like this can be done using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000371/return-value-from-execscriptihtmlwindow2) but as I have said [MSDN says I should use eval instead of execScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/12k71sw7%28v=vs.94%29.aspx). The question is how to call eval and get a return value from my JS function.

Comment: your 2 lines of code doesn't give much info to work on. Post your code.

Comment: @L.B, my whole BHO code is a bit too complicated to post, I can create a demo BHO proj later but the point is that IHTMLWIndow2.exec script is no longer supported and in any case does not work as it should. And I am asking if somebody have example of calling "eval" from c# bho

Comment: I could post some code, but I am not sure what you really want to do. If you don't explain what you actually want to do, we can't help. Read [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=xy+problem) to see what I mean.

Comment: @L.B, funny link :) Added more code.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here?  If you told us what you're trying to accomplish, maybe we can direct you to a better solution.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, my BHO enables advanced spellchecking on some sites. One of such sites is google docs editor. Among everything else I need to be able to get text around cursor. I wrote a JS function which does this and want to call it from my BHO

Comment: I know how to call a JS function from my BHO and accessing the return value, but that's a C++ BHO, and this implies using IDispatch interfaces. Are you interested by some C++ code? Do you know how to translate such code in C#?

Comment: @manuell, if you have such a code - please post it and I will try to translate it into C#

Comment: Will do, but not now. Holiday!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found some links which allow to get return value from JS in C++ BHOs but I haven't managed to convert them in C# so here is a workaround way which worked for me:

```
// Execute method and save return value to a new document property.
ieHtmlWindow2.execScript("document.NewPropForResponse = getElemHtml();");

// Read document property.
var property = ((IExpando)ieHtmlDocument2).GetProperty("NewPropForResponse", BindingFlags.Default);
if (property != null)
    return property.GetValue(ieHtmlDocument2, null);  // returns return value from getElemHtml.
```