# IE COM automation: How to get the return value of `window.execScript` in PowerShell

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, powershell, com, automation

From [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2000371/450913) it looks like it is possible to get the return value of `IHTMLWindow2::execScript` from Internet Explorer API, however the linked example is in C++ and I don't really understand it. I'm trying to do the same thing in **PowerShell**, so here's my code that shows the problem:

```
$ie = New-Object -COM InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate("http://google.com")
while ( $ie.busy ) { start-sleep -m 100 }
$document = $ie.document
$window = $document.parentWindow

Function eval($jsCommand) {
    # Of course it doesn't return anything here. How can I get the return value?
    return $window.execScript($jsCommand, 'javascript')
}

eval 'parseInt("12")' # returns nothing
```

What I'm really trying to do is to make jQuery selector/objects available in my PowerShell script, so that I can do things like:

```
eval '$("input#selector")' | where name -eq 'username'
```

and more.

**Update:** Look at this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/omidkrad/fbb4bfb3b1f5b83c9898) for PowerShell function to run JavaScript/JQuery and return results back to PS, with timeout. It was extended from the answer below.

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536420(v=vs.85).aspx) might be pertinent. Apparently execScript always returns null. This has also been deprecated in IE11

Comment: Good find @Matt now I'm trying to figure how to access the [Global Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/52f50e9t(v=vs.85).aspx) which holds the [eval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/12k71sw7(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Comment: Created a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26023915/450913).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred method is probably what @Matt suggested to use the [eval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/12k71sw7(v=vs.85).aspx) method instead of [execScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536420(v=vs.85).aspx) which has been deprecated in IE11. However, I still couldn't find how to access that `eval` from IE API. I created this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26023915/450913) to follow up with that.

I could, however, figure a way to execute JavaScript/jQuery on a web page and return the results back to PowerShell with this trick that we store the JavaScript return value in the DOM using `setAttribute` and then retrieving it in PowerShell using `getAttribute`.

```
# some web page with jQuery in it
$url = "http://jquery.com/"

# Use this function to run JavaScript on a web page. Your $jsCommand can
# return a value which will be returned by this function unless $global
# switch is specified in which case $jsCommand will be executed in global
# scope and cannot return a value. If you received error 80020101 it means
# you need to fix your JavaScript code.
Function ExecJavaScript($ie, $jsCommand, [switch]$global)
{
    if (!$global) {
        $jsCommand = "document.body.setAttribute('PSResult', (function(){$jsCommand})());"
    }
    $document = $ie.document
    $window = $document.parentWindow
    $window.execScript($jsCommand, 'javascript') | Out-Null
    if (!$global) {
        return $document.body.getAttribute('PSResult')
    }
}

Function CheckJQueryExists
{
    $result = ExecJavaScript $ie 'return window.hasOwnProperty("$");'
    return ($result -eq $true)
}

$ie = New-Object -COM InternetExplorer.Application -Property @{
    Navigate = $url
    Visible = $false
}
do { Start-Sleep -m 100 } while ( $ie.ReadyState -ne 4 )

$jQueryExists = CheckJQueryExists $ie
echo "jQuery exists? $jQueryExists"

# make a jQuery call
ExecJavaScript $ie @'
    // this is JS code, remember to use semicolons
    var content = $('#home-content');
    return content.text();
'@

# Quit and dispose IE COM
$ie.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ie) | out-null
Remove-Variable ie
```

Comment: Look at this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/omidkrad/fbb4bfb3b1f5b83c9898) for PowerShell function to run JavaScript/JQuery and return results back to PS, with timeout. It was extended from this answer.