# Javascript injection with CDHtmlDialog (MFC)

Tags: javascript, c++, html, mfc

Does someone have an example of how to inject Javascript variables with CDHtmlDialog? There don't appear to be any readily available solutions using Google or MSDN. Assume that "window.external" is not available within the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The way you get IHTMLDocument2 is CDHtmlDialog::GetDHtmlDocument. You need to wait for DocumentComplete before accessing the document. [Doing it early may not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853607/how-to-use-getdhtmldocument-in-mfc-programming).

The way you call script is [through the IHTMLWindow2 interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666662/call-a-javascript-function-from-c). You get the window via IHTMLDocument2::parentWindow property. Just declare a variable in the jscript you execute.

Comment: DocumentComplete = NavigateComplete?

Comment: No - the view is created at NavigateComplete2, but most likely the document is still being downloaded. Code injection at this time is not recommended. DocumentComplete is where you should put your code that expects a completed document.